# Android Ping command dies on unreachable server

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ping

I have been trying to attempt to insert a ping command thread into my Android application, and when the server is reachable the code works great. When the server is unreachable, the process hangs and I have no idea why.

This code works in the emulator, whether the host is resolvable or not, however on an actual device, the process.waitFor never returns, and no output is published from the input or output streams.

Any ideas?

```
protected double executePing(String ipAddress) {
    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("/system/bin/ping");
    commands.add("-c");
    commands.add("5");
    commands.add("-w");
    commands.add("5");
    commands.add("128.128.128.128");
    try {
        this.doCommand(commands);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return laten;
}

private void doCommand(List<String> command) throws IOException{

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = pb.start();

    // any error message?
    StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(
            process.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");

    // any output?
    OutputStreamGobbler outputGobbler = new OutputStreamGobbler(
            process.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

    // kick them off
    errorGobbler.start();
    outputGobbler.start();

    // read the output from the command
    try {
        exitVal = process.waitFor();
        //Sleep for 10 secs to try to clear the buffer
        Thread.sleep(6000);

        //pingVal = echo.toString();
        if(exitVal == 0 && !pingVal.isEmpty()){
            //System.out.println("PING STATS: "+pingVal);
            try{
            pingVal = pingVal.substring(pingVal.lastIndexOf("rtt min/avg/max/mdev"));
            pingVal = pingVal.substring(23);
            pingVal = pingVal.substring(pingVal.indexOf("/")+1);
            laten = Double.parseDouble(pingVal.substring(0,pingVal.indexOf("/")));
            }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
                System.out.println("PING VAL: "+ pingVal);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about wrapping the code inseide `executePing` in a `do/while` loop, and keep track of time. Once the time expires, you exit the loop.

Comment: Yeah I was actually thinking about something similar. Essentially spawning a new thread that executes the ping command, then after x amount of time killing the thread by setting it to null and calling thread.interrupt...

Comment: Yeah, that is what I would do. I like the idea of create a new thread, then killing it after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create a new thread to ping, and keep it open for a certain amount of time (call it a timeout). If you don't get the desired response, within the desired time, you can close the thread & try again; or, kill the process. This would give you the ability to check for specific response codes, along with the timeout.

Comment: I did something close to this... I changed the class to implement Callable, then used ExecutorService to create a new SingleThreadExecutor and let it run for two minutes before the executor kills the thread. I'll go ahead and mark your answer as correct, even though I followed a slightly different approach